# how to disable angular2-ladda from HTML and prevent class overwriting by ladda

Tags: javascript, angular, ladda

I'm just beginner to Angular and I have got the following query.

I've used `angular2-ladda` for button loading, I want to keep button disabled when view loads, what I did is as follow,

```
<button [ladda]="isLoading" data-color="mint" data-size="s" class="btn btn-success add-product" disabled="disabled">Add</button>
```

about the first question I've used attribute `disabled` to disable button but it is not working, and the second it overwrites class `btn btn-success`.

for solution what i did is, I've disabled button from `JS` and the `btn btn-success` style applied by `css`.

is there any way to solve this, if yes please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

To disable the button use `[disabled]` property.

```
<button [ladda]="isLoading" data-color="mint" data-size="s" class="btn btn-success add-product" [disabled]="disabled">Add</button>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `disabled` variable is a boolean and it's value is false?

Comment: hey, this worked for me, do you have any solution for Ladda class overwrite issue?

Comment: You can add a css class to the button using `[ngClass]` property. When do this class overridng happens?

Comment: even though i've used `[ngClass]` it overwrites style of `btn btn-success`. I think class overwrites when `[ladda]="isLoading"` is initializes.

Comment: Then add `[ngClass]={'btn-success': isLoading}`